# For loop not being recognized

Tags: c#, for-loop

I am making a simple text based game, but when i try to compile it, it gives me an error on the for loop. It doesn't recognize it and gives me an error the word for and on the end brackets.

```
using System;
namespace ThreeDGame {
class Player {
    private int px=1;
    private int py=1;
    private int pz=1;
    public Player(int x, int y, int z) {
        px=x;
        py=y;
        pz=z;
    }
    public void xp() {
        if (++px=10) {
            px=1;
        }
    }
    public void xn() {
        if (--px=0) {
            px=9;
        }
    }
    public void yp() {
        if (++py=10) {
            py=1;
        }
    }
    public void yn() {
        if (--py=0) {
            py=9;
        }
    }
    public void zp() {
        if (++pz=10) {
            pz=1;
        }
    }
    public void zn() {
        if (--pz=0) {
            pz=9;
        }
    }
}
class Board {
    string[] board = new string[9,9,9];
    for (int x=0; x<9; x++) {
        for (int y=0; y<9; y++) {
            for (int z=0; z<9; z++) {
                board[x,y,z] = "~";
            }
        }
    }
    public void DispBoard(int z) {
        for (int a=1; a>=9; a++) {
            Console.WriteLine();
            for (int b=1; b>=9; b++) {
                Console.Write(board[a-1,b-1,z-1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
class Game {
    static void Main() {
        Board b = new Board();
        b.DispBoard(1);
    }
}
```

}

If anyone knows how to solve this, please share.

Comment: Apart from the error explained in the answer below, the code in the Dispboard will never do what you think it should do. _int a=1; a>=9;_ ? Never true in this universe

Comment: Visual Studio shows some other errors in your code: Problems: ++px =10 , new string[9, 9, 9];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implement `Board` class *constructor*:

```
  class Board {
    //DONE: string[,,] - you want a 3d array, right? 
    string[,,] board = new string[9, 9, 9];

    //DONE: you can't just run loop within the class, but within a constructor (or method)
    public Board() {
      //DONE: do not use magic values (9), but GetLength(dimension) 
      for (int x = 0; x < board.GetLength(0); ++x) 
        for (int y = 0; y < board.GetLength(1); ++y) 
          for (int z = 0; z < board.GetLength(2); ++z) 
            board[x, y, z] = "~";
    } 

    public void DispBoard(int z) {
      //DONE: validate public methods' values 
      if ((z < 1) || (z > board.GetLength(2)))
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("z");

      //DONE: wrong condition ">= 9" changed into right one "< board.GetLength(0)"
      for (int x = 0; x < board.GetLength(0); ++x) {
        Console.WriteLine();

        //DONE: wrong condition ">= 9" changed into right one "< board.GetLength(1)"
        for (int y = 0; y < board.GetLength(1); ++y) 
          Console.Write(board[x, y, z - 1]);
      } 
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

your first loop is not part of a method this part :  `for (int x=0; x<9; x++) ...`

created a method and insert the loops into it

Comment: Probably that code should go into the Board constructor and the board array declared as an instance variable of the class

Comment: I think , it would be better that is should be part of a ClearBoard method. but I agree it should also be called in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a contractor and call the method of loop.

```
class Board {
    public Board(){
        dosometing();
    }
    public void dosometing(){
            string[] board = new string[9,9,9];
        for (int x=0; x<9; x++) {
            for (int y=0; y<9; y++) {
                for (int z=0; z<9; z++) {
                    board[x,y,z] = "~";
                }
            }
        }
        public void DispBoard(int z) {
            for (int a=1; a>=9; a++) {
                Console.WriteLine();
                for (int b=1; b>=9; b++) {
                    Console.Write(board[a-1,b-1,z-1]);
                }
            }
    }
    }
}
```